# react-bootstrap with other components

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get familiar with react and web development. And made my first steps.

Right now I'm using react with react-bootstrap & css modules.
In the main.html I had to include the bootstrap.css file.

I would like to replace my searchbar with [react-autosuggest](http://react-autosuggest.js.org/)

It seems like bootstrap is breaking the style of react-autosuggest. Is it possible to combine both? Or is it a bad practice?

That is my code where I tried to use both searchbars:

```
   import React, {Component} from 'react';
   import styles from  './App.css';
   import Search from "./Search/Search"
   import SearchAuto from "./SearchAuto/SearchAuto"

   class App extends Component {
   render() {
   return (
      <div>
         <div className={styles.App}>
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <Search onSearch={this.searchForAddress}/>
         </div>
         <SearchAuto onSearch={this.searchForAddress}/>
      </div>
   );
   }
   }
   export default App;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Referring to: https://formden.com/blog/isolate-bootstrap, you should isolate bootstrap css that it only is used when a special class is present

Comment: Didn't helped. I even removed  completly the bootstrap css import from my html file. It still look the same. A bit of strage to me (but I'm a newbie in the Web field). I could try to uninstall react-bootstrap.

Comment: update: made a reset of my project. bootstrap isolate works! thanks a lot!